# How to change tailwind css main colors in an angular app

Tags: css, angular, tailwind-css

I have an existing angular application with installed tailwind css.
For example, I have the HTML code below:

```
<p class="color-primary-default font-bold text-xl my-0">Welcome</p>
```

This text is displayed with a given color through **color-primary-default** (I believe) but I don't know where (which file) I could modify the parameters to do so ?

I also don't want to specify explicitly the color inside *class*.

The **tailwind.config.js** looks like this:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  important: true,
  content: [
    "./src/**/*.{html,ts}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Comment: did you check your project tailwind.config.js?

Comment: I did, added it to the question

Comment: It does not look it is coming from tailwind. Try to to a project wide search for 'color-primary-default' to see where it is coming from. But it looks like bootstrap to me or some custom sass mixin/function